# How to use Joda-time property org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.Folder

Tags: java, java-8, jodatime, weblogic12c, tzdata

Currently in our project we are using joda-time version 2.9.9, the project is on production and we need to update the tzdata of jodatime.
Java 1.8
Weblogic 12.2.1.3
tzdata from https://data.iana.org/time-zones/releases/tzdata2023c.tar.gz

When the test server server start, we have an exception.

```
        at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:652)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:420)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:360)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/tz/tzdata2020a/ZoneInfoMap (Is a directory)
        at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.getDefaultProvider(DateTimeZone.java:506)
        at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.getProvider(DateTimeZone.java:413)
        at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(DateTimeZone.java:349)(ExchangeTimingHandlerImpl.java:99)
        ... 82 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/tz/tzdata20223c/ZoneInfoMap (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at org.joda.time.tz.ZoneInfoProvider.openResource(ZoneInfoProvider.java:196)
        at org.joda.time.tz.ZoneInfoProvider.<init>(ZoneInfoProvider.java:74)
        at org.joda.time.DateTimeZone.getDefaultProvider(DateTimeZone.java:503)
        ... 90 more
```

We have been looking into
https://www.joda.org/joda-time/tz_update.html
https://github.com/JodaOrg, but we couldn't find anything related to the property or "ZoneInfoMap (No such file or directory)".

Does any one know the solution?

The idea is to be able to update the tzdata information from Joda-Time library.

The Joda-Time library is inside a framework. Updating the library would mean more work since we don't know what else could fail and certify everything again.

Comment: Why not just use the current version 2.12.5? [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is in [maintenance-mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), so only the most minimal changes are being made. See the [Release Notes](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/changes-report.html#a2.11.2).

Comment: The joda-time library is inside a framework, updating the library means more work since we don't know what else could fail and certify everything again.